# How do I Connect Spring Cloud Stream Functional Beans to a Kafka Binder?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I'm using the [Spring Cloud Streams Documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-function/reference/html/spring-cloud-function.html#_comparing_functional_with_traditional_bean_definitions) to try and work out how to connect my micro service to Kafka via the binder already downloaded in Gradle. I've tried creating a simple `@Bean Function<String, String>()` method within my Spring Boot Application class and have verified that it is able to talk to Kafka by using the command line to interact with the `uppercase-in-0` and `uppercase-out-0` topics, as is described in the beginning of the documentation confirming that the application is able to communicate with Kafka. At this point I attempted to create the following class with the expectation that it would load via auto discovery:

```
package com.yuknis.loggingconsumer;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class LoggingConsumerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LoggingConsumerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

```
package com.yuknis.loggingconsumer.functions;

import java.util.function.Function;

public class CharCounter implements Function<String, Integer> {

    /**
     * Applies this function to the given argument.
     *
     * @param s the function argument
     * @return the function result
     */
    @Override
    public Integer apply(String s) {
        return s.length();
    }

}
```

With the `application.properties` files as such:

```
spring.cloud.function.scan.packages:com.yuknis.loggingconsumer.functions
```

I'm not 100% sure what should happen now, but I'm assuming that it should see the class and automatically create a `charcounter-out-0` and `charcounter-in-0` topic which I could consume and publish to, with the data in those topics going through that function. That's isn't what's happening. What might I be missing? Is this class supposed to create the topic the same way that the `@Bean` would?

Answer (score 1):

Even though each of the functions are loaded with `spring.cloud.function.scan.packages` set to a package and `spring.cloud.function.scan.enabled` set to `true`, it still doesn't create the topics. You'll still need to set `spring.cloud.function.scan.definition` to the `Function`, `Consumer`, or `Supplier` you'd like to have communicate with Kafka like so:

```
spring.cloud.function:
  scan:
    enabled: true
    packages: com.yuknis.loggingconsumer.functions
  definition: charCounter;lowercase;uppercase
```

After that, it will create the `charCounter-in-0` and `charCounter-out-0` topics, which can be mapped if necessary with the `spring.cloud.function.charCounter-in-0` or `spring.cloud.function.charCounter-out-0` expression property.